# Chart.JS labels font-height and offset

Tags: javascript, charts

How can I set the font-height and an offset for the X axis labels in chart.js?

Here's my example and you can see the problem with labels with long names: https://jsfiddle.net/g30hp12f/2/

```
var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: data,
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          min: 0
        }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        },
        ticks: {
          maxRotation: 0,
          minRotation: 0
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```